# Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

What's the easiest way to add an `option` to a dropdown using jQuery?

Will this work?

```
$("#mySelect").append('<option value=1>My option</option>');
```

Comment: Or use `$("#mySelect").html(....)` to replace the current options with the new ones.

Comment: Why not simply?
`$('<option/>').val(optVal).text('some option').appendTo('#mySelect')`

Answer (score 382, accepted):

This did NOT work in IE8 (yet did in FF):

```
$("#selectList").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
```

This DID work:

```
var o = new Option("option text", "value");
/// jquerify the DOM object 'o' so we can use the html method
$(o).html("option text");
$("#selectList").append(o);
```

Answer (score 1023):

Personally, I prefer this syntax for appending options:

```
$('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'My option'
}));
```

If you're adding options from a collection of items, you can do the following:

```
$.each(items, function (i, item) {
    $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.value,
        text : item.text 
    }));
});
```

Comment: this will be quite slow if you're adding a lot of options, compared to just building up a html string and appending it

Comment: KUDOS! I had to add an ID to the option as well, and this is the only way I could find that would add the ID (just add another line below "Text:" saying "ID:"

Answer (score 142):

You can add option using following syntax, Also you can visit to [way handle option in jQuery](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-handle-select-and-option-tag-in.html) for more details.

> 1. `$('#select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One'}));`
> 2. `$('#select').append('<option value="1">One</option>');`
> 3. `var option = new Option(text, value); $('#select').append($(option));`

Comment: The second one has an incorrect attribute in the option tag (`value` instead of `val`). The correct code should be `$('select').append('<option value="1">One</option>');`

Answer (score 45):

If the option name or value is dynamic, you won't want to have to worry about escaping special characters in it; in this you might prefer simple DOM methods:

```
var s= document.getElementById('mySelect');
s.options[s.options.length]= new Option('My option', '1');
```

Comment: Doesn't look so simple to me!!

Comment: This is simple in javascript terms, jquery has made things too easy for people

Comment: document.getElementById('mySelect').add(new Option('My option','1')); // if IE8 or better

Comment: Good point. But also possible with standard jquery methods. Say `let option=$('<option>caption</option>'); option.attr('value', myval); $('select').append(option);`.

Answer (score 45):

This is very simple:

```
$('#select_id').append('<option value="five" selected="selected">Five</option>');
```

or

```
$('#select_id').append($('<option>', {
                    value: 1,
                    text: 'One'
                }));
```

Answer (score 39):

### Option 1-

You can try this-

```
$('#selectID').append($('<option>',
 {
    value: value_variable,
    text : text_variable
}));
```

Like this-

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
     $('#mySelect').append($('<option>',
     {
        value: i,
        text : "Option "+i 
    }));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='mySelect'></select>
```

### Option 2-

Or try this-

```
$('#selectID').append( '<option value="'+value_variable+'">'+text_variable+'</option>' );
```

Like this-

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
     $('#mySelect').append( '<option value="'+i+'">'+'Option '+i+'</option>' );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='mySelect'></select>
```

Answer (score 20):

That works well.

If adding more than one option element, I'd recommend performing the append once as opposed to performing an append on each element.

Answer (score 18):

for whatever reason doing `$("#myselect").append(new Option("text", "text"));` isn't working for me in IE7+

I had to use `$("#myselect").html("<option value='text'>text</option>");`

Comment: I am using that same syntax (new Option(...) on Android Chrome browser (on a phone) and it isn't working there either.

Answer (score 18):

To help performance you should try to only alter the DOM once, even more so if you are adding many options.

```
var html = '';

for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
    html.join('<option value="' + data[i]['value'] + '">' + data[i]['label'] + '</option>');
}           

$('#select').append(html);
```

Comment: to help performance you should use `string.join()` for concatenating strings

Comment: This is a great solution.  I had an issue with "join()" in the example not being a valid function, but this solution allows you to use a jQuery "promise" to determine when all options have been added and the DOM is done updating.  With the other solutions that add options one by one, this cannot be done as easily.  Replace the last line in the example with the following to take an action only after the DOM modification is complete: $.when($('#select').append(html)).done(function () { callSomeFunctionThatRequiresOptionsToBeSet() });

Answer (score 17):

Why not simply?

```js
$('<option/>')
  .val(optionVal)
  .text('some option')
  .appendTo('#mySelect')
```

**Test here:**

```js
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  $('<option/>').val(i).text('option ' + i).appendTo('#mySelect')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$('#mySelect').empty().append('<option value=1>My option</option>').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this solution not only requires jQuery, but also jQueryUI. `selectmenu()` is not part of the jQuery core and is a jQueryUI [widget](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu). That makes it a pretty heavy-handed solution, no?

Answer (score 13):

I like to use non jquery approach:

```
mySelect.add(new Option('My option', 1));
```

Comment: I like it being being non-jquery ;) Don't see that too often

Comment: Yeah, and although I can't question jquery power, there are cases it doesn't simplify things.

Answer (score 11):

```
var select = $('#myselect');
var newOptions = {
                'red' : 'Red',
                'blue' : 'Blue',
                'green' : 'Green',
                'yellow' : 'Yellow'
            };
$('option', select).remove();
$.each(newOptions, function(text, key) {
    var option = new Option(key, text);
    select.append($(option));
});
```

Answer (score 11):

You can add options dynamically into dropdown as shown in below example. Here in this example I have taken array data and binded those array value to dropdown as shown in output screenshot

**Output:**

[image]

```js
var resultData=["Mumbai","Delhi","Chennai","Goa"]
$(document).ready(function(){
   var myselect = $('<select>');
     $.each(resultData, function(index, key) {
      myselect.append( $('<option></option>').val(key).html(key) );
       });
      $('#selectCity').append(myselect.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>

<select  id="selectCity">

</select>
```

Answer (score 10):

Not mentioned in any answer but useful is the case where you want that option to be also selected, you can add:

```
var o = new Option("option text", "value");
o.selected=true;
$("#mySelect").append(o);
```

Comment: Thanks, i needed to preselect an option generated from json and this worked nicely.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to insert the new option at a specific index in the select:

```
$("#my_select option").eq(2).before($('<option>', {
    value: 'New Item',
    text: 'New Item'
}));
```

This will insert the "New Item" as the 3rd item in the select.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways. You can use either of these two.

First:

```
$('#waterTransportationFrom').append('<option value="select" selected="selected">Select From Dropdown List</option>');
```

Second:

```
$.each(dataCollecton, function(val, text) {            
    options.append($('<option></option>').val(text.route).html(text.route));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

> *How about this*

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var option = '';

for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
     option += '<option value="'+ numbers[i] + '">' + numbers[i] + '</option>';
    }

    $('#items').append(option);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can append and set the Value attribute with text:

```
$("#id").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", '').text(''));
$("#id").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", '4').text('Financial Institutions'));
```

Answer (score 3):

if u have **optgroup** inside **select**, u got error in DOM.

I think a best way:

```
$("#select option:last").after($('<option value="1">my option</option>'));
```

Answer (score 3):

We found some problem when you append option and use jquery validate.
You must click one item in select multiple list.
You will add this code to handle:

```
$("#phonelist").append("<option value='"+ 'yournewvalue' +"' >"+ 'yournewvalue' +"</option>");

$("#phonelist option:selected").removeAttr("selected"); // add to remove lase selected

$('#phonelist option[value=' + 'yournewvalue' + ']').attr('selected', true); //add new selected
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOjIY.png]

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
     var option = $("<option></option>");
     option.text("Display text");
     option.val("1");
     $("#Select1").append(option);
});
```

If you getting data from some object, then just forward that object to function...

```
$(function (product) {
     var option = $("<option></option>");
     option.text(product.Name);
     option.val(product.Id);
     $("#Select1").append(option);
});
```

Name and Id are names of object properties...so you can call them whatever you like...And ofcourse if you have Array...you want to build custom function with for loop...and then just call that function in document ready...Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Based on [dule's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447147/6225838) for appending a collection of items, a **one-liner [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** will also work wonders:

```js
let cities = {'ny':'New York','ld':'London','db':'Dubai','pk':'Beijing','tk':'Tokyo','nd':'New Delhi'};

for(let c in cities){$('#selectCity').append($('<option>',{value: c,text: cities[c]}))}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="selectCity"></select>
```

Both object values and indexes are assigned to the options. This solution works even in the old [jQuery (v1.4)](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js)!

Answer (score 3):

If someone comes here looking for a way to add options with data properties

Using **attr**

```
var option = $('<option>', { value: 'the_value', text: 'some text' }).attr('family', model.family);
```

Using **data** - version added 1.2.3

```
var option = $('<option>', { value: 'the_value', text: 'some text' }).data('misc', 'misc-value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select_id').append($('<option>',{ value: v, text: t }));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a quick points for best performance

always when you are dealing with many options, build a big string and then add it to the 'select' for best performance

f.g.

var $mySelect = $('#mySelect');
var str = '';

```
$.each(items, function (i, item) {
    // IMPORTANT: no selectors inside the loop (for the best performance)
    str += "<option value='" + item.value + "'> " + item.text + "</option>";
});
// you built a big string

$mySelect.html(str); // <-- here you add the big string with a lot of options into the selector.
$mySelect.multiSelect('refresh');
```

### Even faster

```
var str = ""; 
for(var i; i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    str += "<option value='" + item[i].value + "'> " + item[i].text + "</option>";
}    
$mySelect.html(str);
$mySelect.multiSelect('refresh');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way i did it, with a button to add each select tag.

```
$(document).on("click","#button",function() {
   $('#id_table_AddTransactions').append('<option></option>')
}
```

Comment: Does it should be `$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button").click(function() {
      $('#id_table_AddTransactions').append('<option></option>');
   });
});`

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. My answer didn't include the ready statement because, I focused on what solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in ES6:

```
$.each(json, (i, val) => {
    $('.js-country-of-birth').append(`<option value="${val.country_code}"> ${val.country} </option>`);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
mySelect.innerHTML+= '<option value=1>My option</option>';
```

```js
btn.onclick= _=> mySelect.innerHTML+= `<option selected>${+new Date}</option>`
```

```html
<button id="btn">Add option</button>

<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

U can try below code to append to option

```
  <select id="mySelect"></select>

    <script>
          $("#mySelect").append($("<option></option>").val("1").html("My enter code hereoption"));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just by single line

```
$.each(result, function (k,v) {
    if(k == selectedMonthNumber) var selectedMonth = 'selected'; else var selectedMonth = '';
    $("#periodMonth").append($('<option>', {
        value: k,
        text: v,
        selected: selectedMonth
    }));
})
```