# Internet Explorer inserting select options from ajax call

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

This seams to work in firefox and chrome, but not internet explorer.  I need this to work in internet explorer.

IE is appending the opening tag and not the inner text and closing tag.
Thanks in advance.

JS:

```javascript
function go() {
   $.post("ajax-select.html", "", function(resp){
      $('#dropdown').append($('#newOptions option', resp));
   }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
   <select id="dropdown">
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="go();" />
</body>
```

ajax-select.html:

```html
<div>
   <div id="newOptions">
      <option value="opOne">one</option>
      <option value="opTwo">two</option>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JonathanSampson Tried that, same results.  innerHTML="<OPTION value="opOne"><OPTION value="opTwo">"

Comment: Solved.  I'm still not sure what the problem was, but if I use div tags instead of option tags.
<option value="opOne">one</option>
<div title="opOne">one</div>
Then replace ajax function with:
$('#newOptions div', resp).each(function(i, d){
   $('#dropdown').append(
      $('<option value="'+d.title'">'+d.innerHTML+'</option>');});

Comment: You're correct about the bad markup, but once you correct that you don't need to change your JavaScript. I just came across the same solution moments ago when troubleshooting your page.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$('#dropdown').html($('#newOptions option', resp));
```

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript) answer

Comment: I think the problem is the way jquery is handling the option tags in IE, not the appending.

Answer (score 1):

Your response is not correct. The actual HTML coming back is:

```
<div>
  <div id="newOptions">
    <div value="opOne">one</div>
    <div value="opTwo">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Correct it, and all works properly:

```
<div>
  <select id="newOptions">
    <option value="opOne">one</option>
    <option value="opTwo">two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

With the above markup (options properly nested within a select element), you can continue using the following:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[value='go']").on("click", function(){
        $.post("ajax-select.html", function(resp){
            $(resp).find("option").appendTo("#dropdown");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a type-o.  It still does not work for me.
http://users.csc.tntech.edu/~elkrohnfel21/testing/select.html

Comment: @Eric Which version of IE are you testing against? This is working just fine for me in IE10.