# Appending options to a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

This is related to [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript) but has a different focus

My problem is that I am not able to append option-elements to a select in IE8.
When changing the engine to IE7 in IE's developer-tools it does work.

It also works in FF and Chrome.

```
var valT = "some Text";
var charsToIgnore = 2;

var o = new Option(valT.slice(charsToIgnore), valT);
$(o).html(valT.slice(charsToIgnore));
$('#availablePages').append(o);
```

another method I tried:

```
$('<option/>', {value: valT, text: valT}).appendTo("#availablePages");
```

`availablePages` is the id of my select. The select does not contain any elements when the page is received by the client. My doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I also tried to remove all other scripts and css from my site to make sure no side-effects apply.

**Edit:\ Thanks for downvoting!** It's not my fault if provided solutions do not work in all IE8-versions. Since my question was *What DOES work in all IE8-versions?* it is, from my point of view, understandable that I do not accept answers which do not work for me. As you can see in [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript) I am not the only one for whom the other replies here do not work. 
Using the Up-/Down-Vote functionalities as channel for your own mood is no good Wiki/QA-behaviour.

Comment: `$(o).html(valT.slice(charsToIgnore));` <-- that line seems redundant, since `new Option("a", "b");`  already returns `<option value="b">a</option>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What worked for me

```
  var o = new Option("option text", "value");
  $(o).html("option text");  // Without this line it does not work..
  $("#availablePages").append(o);
```

What I also had to change / what one should consider:

- `display: table;` is **NOT** allowed to be applied. For some reason it breaks everything.

Answer (score 1):

This should just do the trick for you:

```
$('#availablePages').append(new Option(valT.slice(charsToIgnore), valT));
```

(Tested and working in IE8)

Comment: does not work for me :( Which exact version of IE are you running? I'm running 8.0.6001

Comment: IE 9 in IE 8 compatibility mode, actually. But that shouldn't be different. Are you certain `$('#availablePages')` exists?

Comment: Yup. As said, it also works in other browsers + IE8 in IE7-mode. There is also no other script-code left on that site