# Setting elements of a listbox through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I set the individual elements of a listbox jsf generated for me ? I want to set it through JS.

```
HTML generated: <select id="pageForm:effectiveDateListbox" name="pageForm:effectiveDateListbox" multiple="multiple" size="0"></select>   

var listBox = document.getElementById('pageForm:effectiveDateListbox');
            for (i = 0; i!= length; i++) 
            {
                var date = arrDates[i];
                var displayMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var displayYear = date.getFullYear();
                var displayDate = date.getDate();
                tokenizedDates = displayMonth.toString(10) + "/" + displayDate.toString(10) + "/" + displayYear.toString(10);
                listBox.options[i].value = tokenizedDates;
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: You don't need the `i++` at the end of your loop as the loop itself will increment it.

Answer (score 0):

in the loop length should be arrDates.length

don't double increment i

declare i and tokenizedDates with var or you pollute the global namespace

Here is the link for doing dom manipulations: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

Here is how to do it with jquery because dom manipulations are tricky to get them to work cross browser:

[Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var listBox = document.getElementById('pageForm:effectiveDateListbox');
var dates = [new Date(2013,01,01), new Date(2013,02,03), new Date(2013,03,03)];    
for (i = 0; i != dates.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var optionText = [dates[i].getMonth() + 1, dates[i].getDate(), dates[i].getFullYear()];
    option.text = optionText.join("/");
    listBox.add(option, null);
}
```