# Dynamically add numbers to select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a way of adding numbers to a select determined by a variable.

For example, **newnumber = 3;** so then populate the select with 3 (including 0)

```
<select class="element" id="element" name="element">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: And you want to do it on demand?

Comment: @KaarelKont-Kontson Nothing substantial, everything I've tried has gone horribly wrong lol

Comment: It's possible by using javascript. By using jQuery for example. Did you try using jQuery for this already?

Comment: I was using jQuery in my attempts yes.

Comment: Where do you get the variable from? User input?

Comment: @Sylvain It's generated by another select menu. Simply returns a whole number.

Comment: Did you attemt to use google? "jquery append option to select" second result: [Adding options to a select using Jquery/javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: for looping activity, use `for loop`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work using JQuery:

```
var selectElement = $('#element');
for (var i = 0; i <= yourVariable; i++) {
    selectElement.append('<option value="' +i +'">' + i + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Ud6eG/)

**HTML**

```
<select class="add"></select>
```

**JS**

```
function add_options(x){
    var opt;
    for(var i=0;i<=x;i++){
        opt += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'
    }
    return opt;
}

$('select.add').append(add_options(3));
```

**output**

```
<select class="add">undefined
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
<select id='example-select'>
</select>

function populateSelectByNumber(howmany,id) {
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  for (var i=0;i<howmany;i++) { 
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
  }
}
populateSelectByNumber(5,'example-select')
```

Answer (score 0):

When that newnumber is generated then you can dynamically create your select element.

```
$("#element").empty();
for(var i = 0; i <= newnumber; i++){
  $("#element").append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Linq Query should retrieve the value based on the attribute value...

```
string input = "<xml string>"
string key = "3";
XElement root = XElement.Parse(input);
var output = (from el in root.Elements("option")
              where (string)el.Attribute("value") == key
              select el).First().Value;
```