# editable dropdown (g:select) grails

Tags: javascript, grails

I want to make an editable g:select in grails. I have an g:select with my default values but I want to can add some from hand. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
<g:select name="selectName" from="${yourValue}"
              optionKey="field" optionValue="field" class="form-control" noSelection="['': '']" value="${defaultValue}"/>
```

optionKey="field" -- if you have an list of objects(view)
optionValue="field" -- if you have an list of objects(send to server)

in from u can add something like this:

```
from="${["1","2","3"]}"
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? I don't think that the given example allows the user to add a new option that is not specified by the values of the 'from' attribute.

Comment: Elementary. His question was: how can I add my own value to g:select? Answer: <g:select form="${youValue+[yourOwnVAlues]}" name="values"/>

Comment: I was under the impression that the question was how to make a g:select where the user has the possibility to add a new value. So you get a sort of input field where the user can pick an option from a combobox and enter a new value.