# Unable to populate dropdown in jquery modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On click of 'create new button' I am poping up a modal window form which has a dropdown . I am populating dropdown via ajax with populateUserData(). I can see that call has been made succesfully, but still not able to see data in a dropdown.
 Help me to figure out what wrong I am doing thanks.

```
      <form id="formAddUser" action="#" title="Add User to Group" style="display: none;">       
     <label for="userId"><strong>User Id</strong></label>
      <select name="" id="userId" rel="0">
            <option>Select</option>              
     </select>  
     <label for="active"><strong>Active</strong></label>
     <select name="actvUsr" id="actvUsr" rel="1">
            <option value="Y">Yes</option>
            <option value="N">No</option>
    </select>  
   <button id="userGrpOk" >OK</button>
   <button id="usrGrpCancel">Cancel</button>
   </form>

    <button type="button" id="addusr">CREATE NEW</button>
```

Javascript

```
  var userDtl = $( "#formAddUser" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        });

       // open modal form.
       $( "#addusr" ).button().on( "click", function() {
               populateUserData();
               userDtl.dialog( "open" );
           });


 function populateUserData() { 
    var userDataXML = ajax data
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : getUserdata',
        data : userDataXML,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        async : false,
        success : function(jqXHR, textStatus,response) {
            var shtml='';
            $.each(jqXHR,function(index, data) {
                shtml+='<option value="'+data.name+'">'+data.name+'</option>';
                $("#userId").html("");
                $("#userId").html(shtml);

            });
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");

        }
    });
```

}

Comment: You have a rogue single-quote on your `url:` line of your ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But actual url m using is this      url : contextRoot + '/getUserData',

Comment: You should also provide the exact code (except for sensitive information such as login info). Otherwise, you could be leaving out something critical.

Comment: ^ that should be "always", not "also"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that :

- you are entering the `success` callback function,
- the jqXHR data is correct,

then try this inside your `$.each()` :

[Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

That will give you :

```
success : function(jqXHR, textStatus,response) {
    var $select = $("#userId");
    $.each(jqXHR,function(index, data) {
        $select.append('<option value="'+data.name+'">'+data.name+'</option>');
    });
}
```

---

**EDIT** :
Notice that you melted parameters order in the `success` function. jQuery doc says :

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the above code still  no luck.

Comment: So the pb is in the data you received from the server ... Try some console.log() in each loop to know if engine is entering the callback function and if the received data is correct.

Comment: <option value="Vitaliy Matiyash(matiyvi)">Vitaliy Matiyash(matiyvi)</option><option value="Shilpi Chakraborty(shilpi)">Shilpi Chakraborty(shilpi)</option><option value="Sal Fragale(fragasa)">Sal Fragale(fragasa)</option><option value="Azarudeen Ashraf Ali(z697847)">Azarudeen Ashraf Ali(z697847)</option><option value="Manohar Rachapalli(w086003)">Manohar Rachapalli(w086003)</option> This is the data I am getting . Its working fine on Primary page problem is having it populate in modal.

Comment: You mean you have two DOM elements with the same ID `userId` ? It will never work, an ID should be unique. Are you sure your selector is working good. Did you try to log it to the console to verify. If the data is good, you probably have a pb with the selector ... As you do not provide a fiddle with the pb, it is difficult to solve it ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was having a duplicate id which was causing the problem.