# Transparent/Invisible value is appending in drop down list

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code which requests some list of objects using getjson method. Controller action method returns list of objects properly. Following code appends requested data in drop down list, but it is invisible/transparent data means it is appending my data but it is not visible i.e. it white/transparent. Here is the code:

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {



            $('#b1').click(function () {

                var userName = "Hello"

                $.getJSON("/classes/getCourseList?username=" + userName, function (data1) {

                    var myOptions =
                        {
                            val1: data1.title

                        };

                    var $mySelect = $('#s1');
                    $.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
                        $mySelect.append($('<option />',
                            {

                                value: val,
                                text: text
                            }));
                    });



                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Action method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult getCourseList(string userName)
        {

            // Quiz q=new Quiz();
            //q = _db.Quizzes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuizName.Equals(userName));
            List<dummyCourses> list = new List<dummyCourses>();

            foreach (Course c in db.Courses) 
            {
                dummyCourses dc = new dummyCourses();
                dc.title = c.title;
                dc.creditHours = c.creditHours;
                dc.instructor = c.instructor;
                dc.code = c.code;
                list.Add(dc);
            }
            return this.Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

Comment: This solutions may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: What structure did you recive from action? I think it's something like `[ { "title": "Title", ... }, ... ]` I mean array of objects, but you use `data1.title` (it will be `undefined`) in your code. Try `data1[ 0 ].title`.

Comment: @ostapische Thanks a lot it was the mistake , you can post it as your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recive structure like:

```
[ { "title": "Title", ... }, ... ]
```

I mean array of objects, but you use `data1.title` (it will be `undefined`) in your code.

It must be `data1[ 0 ].title`, `data1[ 1 ].title`, etc.