# Dynamically Add Select Options with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been working on trying to populate a select tag options with JavaScript. I can't seem to figure out why my function isn't working any help would be greatly appreciated.

My HTML code:

```
    <select name="options" id="options" style="width: 100px;" onchange="chooseOption(this);">
</select>
```

And my JavaScript function:

```
    function chooseOption(){
    var choices = {"Gym","Pool","Sports"};
    var myChoice = "";

  for(i=0; i<=choices.length; i++){
    myChoice += "<option value='"+choices[i]+"'>"+choices[i]+"</option>";
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML = myChoice;
  }

}
```

Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery/JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to create an object instead of an array here:

```
var choices = {"Gym","Pool","Sports"}; // change {} to [] to create an array
```

Curly braces - `{}` are used to denote that you are creating an object.

Brackets - `[]` are used to denote an array.

Try populating your `select` element as it's being created with something like this:

```
<select name="options" id="options" style="width: 100px;">
<script>
var choices = ["Gym","Pool","Sports"];
var myChoice = "";
for(var i=0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    myChoice += "<option value='"+choices[i]+"'>"+choices[i]+"</option>";
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML = myChoice;
}
</script>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this jsfiddle and its still not loading correctly....https://jsfiddle.net/nvzwx46g/3/

Comment: @user1805086 Place all the code from my answer directly in the html section and it will work properly --> https://jsfiddle.net/nvzwx46g/8/

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like.
Is not really tested but am pretty sure is more reliable.

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
  for(i=0; i<=choices.length; i++){
    option.text = choices[i];
    option.value = choices[i];
    document.getElementById("options").appendChild = myChoice;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks...that was dump mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a huge error.

You don't use `{` and `}` in javascript to create arrays.

Use:

```
var choices = ["Gym","Pool","Sports"];
```

Here is your final code:

```
<script>
    function chooseOption() {
        var choices = ["Gym", "Pool", "Sports"];
        var myChoice = "";

        for (i = 0; i <= choices.length; i++) {
            myChoice += "<option value='" + choices[i] + "'>" + choices[i] + "</option>";
            document.getElementById("options").innerHTML = myChoice;
        }

    }

</script>
<select name="options" id="options" style="width: 100px;" onclick="javascript:chooseOption(this);">
</select>
```

## Update

If you want it to work on JSFiddle firstly you need to make your function globally available because JSFiddle runs it at `domready`. To make it globally available just write it like this: `window.choseOption = function() { /* code here */ };`.

You should read a bit on [DOM events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). The change event on that `select` won't fire up until you have selected something. And since you have nothing to select the event will not fire.

You can run the function at `onclick` or just run it when the DOM is ready.

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvzwx46g/9/).

Comment: Thanks...that was dump mistake on my part

Comment: I updated the code change in jsfiddle and its still not loading probably at all....https://jsfiddle.net/nvzwx46g/