# Javascript JQuery append does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am attempting to dynamically add some content to some content that was just dynamically added. I want to put a bunch of `OPTION` items into a `SELECT` that I just added. The `SELECT` is added along with some code from an external .php file (see below). This div appears just fine. However, the contents that I attempt to add inside the `SELECT` does not appear. My `SELECT` is simply empty. I get no errors. The console output in the code below checks out and prints what I expect it to.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$.get("test-new-product-modal.php", function(data){
    $(".modal-body").html(data);
});
$divSelect = $("#product-list");
for(var i = 0; i<(arrayProductTypes.length); i++){
    $divOption = $("option", {'value' : i});
    $divOption.html(arrayProductTypes[i][0]);
    $divSelect.append($divOption);
    console.log("Product ID at "+i+" is: "+arrayProductTypes[i][0]);
}
```

Here is the .php file that I add HTML from:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4>Välj en produkt.</h4>
        <select id="product-list" class="form-control">
            <!-- <option>DRA</option>
            <option>DRB</option> -->
        </select>

        <div class="divider-line"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <p class="product-add-description">Text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle or plunkr that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Dont declare variables using `$`. That is PHP syntaxt. Use `var divSelect = ` instead.

Comment: using `$` can denote jquery object

Comment: Try creating the option like this: $("<option>", ...) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: FYI, `select` & `option` elements are not 'divs'. A `div` is a html element, like `select` & `option` but has entirely different uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery add() method

```
$.get("test-new-product-modal.php", function(data){
    $(".modal-body").html(data);
});
$divSelect = $("#product-list");
for(var i = 0; i<(arrayProductTypes.length); i++){
    $divOption = $("option", {'value' : i});
    $divOption.html(arrayProductTypes[i][0]);
    $divSelect.add($divOption);
    console.log("Product ID at "+i+" is: "+arrayProductTypes[i][0]);
}
```

you can find the doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Answer (score 1):

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e6p3jgf/1/) of something similar to what you are expecting:

It's a lot simpler to add in a HTML element like this:

```
.append('<option value="' + array[i] + '">' + array[i] + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe its how you declare your option object try this:

```
$divOption = $("<option>").attr('value',i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding `options` correctly. If you want to add `options` like jquery `object` you can do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < (arrayProductTypes.length) ; i++) {
     $divOption = $('<option></option>').val(i).html(arrayProductTypes[i][0])
     $divSelect.append($divOption);
     console.log("Product ID at " + i + " is: " + arrayProductTypes[i][0]);
 }
```

This line `$divOption = $("option", {'value' : i});` doesn't return the `option` object instead it is returning an empty array so you need to use

`$('<option></option>').val(i).html("somehtml")` to return an `option`.

Comment: This didn't work either :/ I do believe there is something wrong with finding the SELECT element. Calling a .remove on it does not remove it. But if I try the exact same on another element (not added from the external file) it works.

Comment: Simply run this from console `$("#product-list");` to see if it finds the `select`

Comment: Hm yeah, it does find the element. I guess that's not it then. Now I've tried every suggestion posted to my question and none of them work.

Comment: Can u see the console if there is any error because this worked for me perfectly.

Comment: No errors in he console, no. I've done this type of dynamic content a lots before on the same page with no error. It simply stops workning now that I am looking for an id that only exists in an external .php file that I copy and paste the data of using JS.