# Append data to <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a row that I am cloning sometimes.

```
<script id="SubRow10" type="text/template">
  <select id="SubSelect10" class="form-control" name="SubcategorySelect" required>
    <option value="m,2">Op1</option>
    <option value="m,3">Op2</option>
    <option value="m,5">Op3</option>
    <option value="m,6">Op4</option>
  </select>
</script>
```

I have a form to add an option to `"#Subselect10"`
But when I do this:

```
$('#SubSelect10').append('<option value="m,8">Op5</option>');
```

It does not work, but when I do this:

```
$('#SubRow10').append('<option value="m,8">Op5</option>');
```

It works, but it won't add it to the Select menu.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/notify/n860k20w/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```js
var template = $('#SubRow10');

template.html($(template.html()).append('<option value="m,8">Op5</option>'));

console.log(template.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="SubRow10" type="text/template">
  <select id="SubSelect10" class="form-control" name="SubcategorySelect" required>
    <option value="m,2">Op1</option>
    <option value="m,3">Op2</option>
    <option value="m,5">Op3</option>
    <option value="m,6">Op4</option>
  </select>
</script>
```

The problem is that `<script>` tags do not render their contents as HTML, but as text, even if the `type` is not `text/javascript`. In order to circumvent the problem, you need to parse the contents as HTML before injecting another `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the issue is that your string, `"<option value="m,8">Op5</option>"` contains a double quote, so JavaScript treats it as two different separate parameters to the function. Try either escaping the double quotes in the string (use `\"` instead) or use single quotes to wrap the string, e.g.

```
$("#SubRow10").append('<option value="m,8">Op5</option>')
```

Comment: My bad was mistake in copy/pasting code changed it.

Comment: I've copied your code into JSFiddle, and it seems to work without any trouble. Can you try to post an example that isn't working as expected?

Comment: Added a JSfiddle see main post

Comment: It looks like it will work outside of a `<script type="text/template">` tag. How exactly are you using the template?

Comment: I am using the script tags so the HTML wil be hidden i know i van use the hide class in bootstrap but personaly the script tag is nicer.

Comment: I don't think it's a better solution though, because it isn't inserted into the DOM so jQuery can't access it and manipulate it. Try using CSS to hide it instead.