# select.append adds the option but dropdown is still empty

Tags: jquery

I am populating dropdown using jquery ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Appointment.aspx/BindAssociates",
            data: "{storeNumber:" + StoreNum + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                var rs = result.d;
                var selectAdd = $("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName");
                var selectView = $("#MST_CPH_ViewAppointments_ddlViewAptAssociateName");

                for (var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
                    var opt = rs[i].trim().toUpperCase();
                    //var optView = rs[i].trim();
                    selectAdd.append(new Option(opt,opt));
                    selectView.append(new Option(opt,opt));

                }
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert("Failed to load dropdown" + result);
            }
        });
```

When i debug I can see that success method is executed. but dropdowns still show empty on UI. I am using jquery 1.11.3 and IE8. (Don't ask me why as its the organization requirement). Please help me with this.

Comment: Bug report: [In IE8 .append does not append option elements correctly](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11492) -> _closed (wont fix)_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery/JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: thanks a lot for letting me know. let me try the alternative

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to append option in select.

```
$.each(rs, function (i, item) {
    selectAdd.append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.value,
        text : item.text 
    }));
    selectView.append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.value,
        text : item.text 
    }));
});
```

//alternative using javascript

```
$.each(rs, function(key, item)
{
  output.push('<option value="'+ item.value +'">'+ item.text +'</option>');
});

document.getElementById('MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName').innerHTML = (output.join(''));

document.getElementById('MST_CPH_ViewAppointments_ddlViewAptAssociateName').innerHTML = (output.join(''));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I just tried this code but dropdown is showing empty. If i debug i see that it goes through this code but nothing is showing in the dropdown. i don't know whats happening.

Comment: Can you please share the your response look a like?

Comment: i think options are there but they are not visible somehow because when i open the dropdown it opens a long as if there are many options.

Comment: also if i use IE10 and jquery 3.0 it works perfectly fine. but I have to get this working on IE8

Comment: May be the options are generated but the text may not be appended. Can you please do inspect element and check what exactly happening over there?

Comment: @Prabi Please try with my alternative way also from the update answer.