# Loading data to html is not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, leaflet

I have two pages (html & js),I have data returned from ajax (from database),i made spatial query on it and i want to load some of its data in an input (listbox) in html page but it is not working (no data is loaded in the listbox).
This is the part of html:

```
<div>
<select name="FarmersID" id="FarmersID" multiple style="width:172px">   
</select>
</div>
```

and this is the ajax part

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"CustomerID_geojson.php",
        data:{'OrdersID': Order_ID} ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) { 
           var unit = 'kilometers';
           var buffered = turf.buffer(response, distance, unit);
           bufresult = buffered.geometry.coordinates;
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'allfarmers_geojson.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    var searchWithin = {
                      "type": "FeatureCollection",
                      "features": [
                        {
                          "type": "Feature",
                          "properties": {},
                          "geometry": {
                            "type": "Polygon",
                            "coordinates": bufresult
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    };

                    var ptsWithin = turf.within(data,searchWithin);
                    //to check if there are any farmers within the distance or not
                    if (ptsWithin.features.length > 0)
                    {
                        geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(ptsWithin,
                            {
                                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) 
                                {
                                    FarmerID=feature.properties.Farm_id;
                                    document.getElementById('FarmersID').value=FarmerID; ///This one is not working
                                    layer.bindPopup('<label>Farmer Name:</label>' + feature.properties.nick_name_ + '<br><label>Farmer ID:</label>' + feature.properties.Farm_id);
                                }
                            }).addTo(mymap);
                        mymap.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("No Farmers Found!");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: @Dylan Hamilton...can you check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#FarmersID').append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'My option'
}));
```

[reffer this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447147/3209345)

I hope this is what u want to do add options to your select item via ajax response.

Comment: Thanks :)...It works...but can you tell me "1" in the value refer to what?

Comment: value 1 is value of option element we are adding to your select the above script will add **<option value = "1"> My Option</option>** to your select element. Your can set value which is required for u.