# Ajax append Data to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database

I need to add the data to the database and meanwhile load into a select options menu, I successfully added the data and when loading the data gets duplicated in the options menu

```
function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';
    $.each( data, function( i, o ) {
        rows += '<option>'+o.salary_wage+'</option>';
    });
    $(".selectpicker111").append(rows);
}
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript ?

Comment: Try $(".selectpicker111>*").remove(); from the begin then append :)

Comment: Or do `.html()` instead of `.append()`;

Comment: @ArunaWarnasooriya this didnt work and clears everything

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Thanks so much it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
$("selector").append(rows);
```

This will `append` options to existing options and you will get duplicate options.

There are 2 ways to get rid of duplicate options:

**Option 1:**

Remove existing options before adding options using [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) and then you can add options using either [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) or [html](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString).

```
$("selector").empty();
```

**Option 2:**

Replace existing options with new options using [html](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString)

```
$("selector").html(newOptions);
```

**In your case:**

```
$(".selectpicker111").html(rows);
```