# How I Can get the value of Element of HTML Tag and store that value in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose i have a Tag select in which i have a value section which is holding Dynamic value (its a token). I want to store that value under the tag to a variable. below is the tag name:

```
<option value="XXX|123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789">
```

I want to store whole value. How this can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can get the chosen value of a `select` element by using the `val()` method within a `change` event handler. There's *lots* of questions covering how to do that already, if you take the time to search.

Comment: I have a tag name <option value="XXX|123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"> I want to store the value in a variable and want to use that value in another tag.

Comment: Store option value on click or select?

Comment: You want to do this for one element or several? If for one element you can use var myVar = $("#your-element-id").val();

Comment: [Check out the jQuery docs, it's all there.](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: on Click option

Comment: @KapilBisht don't use `click` for `select` elements (or checkboxes or radios for that matter). Use the `change` event: http://api.jquery.com/change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `$el.val()` method returns the value of the selected element. here you can pass `option:selected` for the select item context to get the selected option's value. The following solution might be helpful to you:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on('change', 'selector_for_select',function () {
                var my_val = $('option:selected',this).val();
                //Do with it what ever you want
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks Vishal. One more thing i want to put this value (my_val) in <option value=my_val>xyz </option> How I can do this?

Comment: The `<option *>` must be having datalist or select parent. If <option value=my_val> is new set then you can append it...

Comment: Sorry to say, I am new to this can you please explain it more. through code is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript). It may help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are missing is `selector`. Assign `id` or `class` attribute to the `<option>` or whatever input. *(If it is a form then you need to assign it a `name` attribute.)* This will help you to access the value from your script.

Like this

`<input type='hidden' id="my_hidden_value" value="YOUR_VALUE">`

To access

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'button_selector',function () {
        var my_val = $('#my_hidden_value').val();
        //Do with it what ever you want
    })
});
</script>
```

### or

`<input type='hidden' class="my_hidden_value" value="YOUR_VALUE">`

To Access

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'button_selector',function () {
        var my_val = $('.my_hidden_value').eq(0).val();
        //Do with it what ever you want
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Mr Sahu your previous syntax have given me the answer.