# jquery selector works but document.getElementById doesn't for adding ES6 event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm brand new to Javascript and trying to attach an event handler to a select list. Here is my html:

```
<select id="x_selector"></select>
```

to which I'm adding a bunch of option entries successfully. However I want to add an on change method. This jquery javascript works:

```
let xsel = $("#x_selector");
xsel.on("change", event => {console.log(event)});
```

But this doesn't:

```
var xSelector = document.getElementById('x_selector');
xSelector.on("change", event => {console.log(event)});
```

With the latter one I get a console TypeError: xSelector.on is not a function.

So what is the difference between document.getElementById and the jquery selector?

Comment: `.on()` is a jquery method so, you not used in javascript, for javascript you try `.addEventListener("change", function(){`

Comment: *So what is the difference* : `$(sel)` gives you a jquery object while `.getElementById` gives you a document node.  You can get the node from jquery with `$(sel).get(0)`  and the other way by wrapping in `$()` eg `$(xSelector)`.  The jquery 'selector' does not have to be text, it can be a DOM node.  As they are different object types, you get different methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.on` is a jQuery method. With vanilla javascript, use `.addEventListener`.

Comment: or try this : $(xSelector).on("change", event => {console.log(event)}); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: thanks, now I have both in there because I need to add options programatically too. this works: xSelector.add(new Option("test", "test")); but I don't know how to do this in jquery. Seems silly to have a mix of jquery and getElementById on the same page...

Comment: @thomas xSelector.append($("<option>",{...})); maybe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery

Comment: @Thomas exactly, if you have included jQuery you should as well use it.

Comment: @Jonas w so what exactly is the syntax within { and } if I want to add to do exactly the same as xSelector.add(new Option("test", "test")); ?

Comment: @thomas its an options object. Have a look at http://docs.jquery.com or the answer ive linked to for more info

Comment: @Jonas w yep got it now! JS sure is a language where this is "more than one way to do stuff!!". So I have xsel.append($("<option>")", {value: "test", text: "test"})) and works a charm

Comment: @thomas browne js is rather a language which is easily extensible. Thats why there are so much librarys/utilities etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:** pure working

```js
document.getElementById("x_selector").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("x_selector");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="x_selector">
```

Comment: This is neither related to the question nor is this a good code.

Comment: Agreed, `document.getElementById("x_selector")` should be cached.

Comment: @jeremy thille this?

Comment: This what? What's the question?