# Dropdown list in Jquery onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is for onclick to get dropdown and changes the text .
Everytime on change I want to post the value into database.

**index.html**

```
    <div id='fullname'></div>
```

**script.js**

```
    $('#fullname').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('');
    $('<select>', { 'name': 'fname', 'id': 'txt_fullname'         
   })
    .append($('<option>', 
     {'value':'Hardware_Problem','text':'Hardware_Problem'},'</option>'))
    .append($('<option>', { 'value':'Software_Problem','text':'Software_Problem'},'</option>'))
    .appendTo('#fullname');
    $('#txt_fullname').focus();
});

        $(document).on('blur','#txt_fullname', function(){
            var name = $(this).val();
            $('#fullname').text(name);
        });
```

Comment: `$('<select>', {
        'name': 'fname',
        'id': 'txt_fullname'       
     }).append($('<option>', { text : SomeText})).appendTo('#fullname')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery

Comment: @Satpal i want options there

Comment: @mohansriramakrishnaP, Go on adding then using `.append($('<option>', { text : SomeText})).`

Comment: Thank you  @Satpal

Comment: @Satpal how to get that value after blur and post it to database