# javascript and ado.db loop + option value not working

Tags: javascript, ado

i'm very new to this. can anyone help me understand how to get the "option value" in a ado loop? thanks so much!

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Select Member 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select class="js-select">
            <script>
                var objConnection = new ActiveXObject("adodb.connection");
                var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=localhost;database=mydatabase";
                objConnection.Open(strConn);
                var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
                var strQuery = "SELECT ID, Member FROM tblMembers order by Member";
                rs.Open(strQuery, objConnection);
                rs.MoveFirst();
                while (!rs.EOF)
                    <Option value={
                    document.write(rs.fields(0));>
                    document.write(rs.fields(1));
                    rs.movenext();
                    }</Option>
                rs.close;
                objConnection.close;
            </script>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: See [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery) - **But** this code will only ever work in Internet Explorer 10 or below and then only for computers you have control over.

Comment: sorry i'm looking at the thread and i can't follow how it would get the rs.field value. can you please elaborate? tyvm!

Comment: @Skal. thanks for closing the div. i forgot to include it.