# Loop over API JSON result and map to select option

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I've been googling for the past hour and can't seem to find any posts relevant to my question.

I'm trying to loop over all the results from an API request and map it accordingly as a select option.

Here's my code:

```
<script>

var urlRoot = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/';
var sourceList = 'sources?';
var apiLanguage = 'language=en&';
var apiKey = 'XXX';

$(document).ready( function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: urlRoot + sourceList + apiLanguage + apiKey,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.sources);
        $.each(data, function(sources, name) {
          $('#source-selection').append(name);
        })
      });
    });
</script>

<select>
  <option> Show Everything </option>
  <option id="source-selection"></option>
</select>
```

The API returns the sources as an array of ~80.

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

Comment: I suppose you want do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery#14447147 . If so, `mySelect` id is on `<select>` tag instead of `<option>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to add each item in `data.sources` as an `option` in your `select`, you first need to iterate over `data.sources` and then append each item to `select`. Also, make sure you add a `value` attribute to each `option` in the list:

**Edit:** For security, use `val` and `text` to set the properties on a new `option` element directly:

```
<script>

var urlRoot = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/';
var sourceList = 'sources?';
var apiLanguage = 'language=en&';
var apiKey = 'XXX';

$(document).ready( function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: urlRoot + sourceList + apiLanguage + apiKey,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    }).then(function(data) {

        console.log(data.sources);

        $.each(data.sources, function(index, value) {

          var $option = $("<option></option>");

          $option.val(value);
          $option.text(value);

          $('#source-selection').append($option);

        });
      });
    });
</script>

<select id="source-selection">
  <option value="everything">Show Everything </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for your response. Could you elaborate on the (index, value) portion of that snippet? And also, it's showing all the options as "object Object" right now. Thank you.

Comment: It's extremely important that you escape your data when injecting it into HTML.  As is right now, you're opening yourself up to a broken application or even some security issues.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, made an edit to code to let jQuery handle the escaping.