# Trouble with chosen js

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I'm using [chosen js](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) lib:

```
<select class="chosen-select" name="country" id="country"  onchange="setCountry('client');">
   ...
</select>
```

Then i need change this select element:

```
$("#country").append('<option value="'+ countryid +'">' + countryname  + '</option>');
```

But it doesn't work with this lib and works without.
How i can fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

After editing element i must to use this code and it works

Answer (score 1):

By using the below code you can attain your goal.

```js
var currentelement = document.querySelector('#country');
        var newOptionElement = document.createElement("option");
        newOptionElement.text = "Test";
        currentelement.add(newOptionElement);
        var newOptionElement = document.createElement("option");
        newOptionElement.text = "Test1";
        currentelement.add(newOptionElement);
        var newOptionElement = document.createElement("option");
        newOptionElement.text = "Test2";
        currentelement.add(newOptionElement);
```

```html
<select class="chosen-select" name="country" id="country">
    </select>
```

```
    var currentelement = document.querySelector('#country');
    var newOptionElement = document.createElement("option");
    newOptionElement.text = "Test";
    currentelement.add(newOptionElement);
```

Comment: but why i can't use jquery?

Comment: You can use jQuery like this approach 
`$("#country").append(new Option("option text", "value"));`