# How to get dynamic fields with Flask?

Tags: jquery, html, python-3.x, flask, dynamic

I'am trying to build a web app that can dynamically get more fields

The app is for getting a hamburger shop orders so there would be orders of lets say 1 hamburger or 7 hamburgers, I tried some code I found out but i having troubles to process the data of the orders and save them into a date base

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Comander {% endblock %}

{% block main %} <form class="/comander" method="post">

<head>   <meta charset="utf-6">   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </head>

<!--Hasta arriva del panel--> <div class="container">   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Burgers</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">


<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" id="formule" name="formule">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Formule</option>
        <option value="1">Classique</option>
        <option value="2">Big</option>
        <option value="3">Veggie</option>
      </select>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" id="fromage" name="fromage">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Fromage</option>
        <option value="1">Chedar</option>
        <option value="2">Tomme</option>
        <option value="3">Blue</option>
        <option value="4">Chevre</option>
        <option value="5">Cantal</option>
        <option value="6">Reblochon</option>
        <option value="7">Maroille</option>
        <option value="8">Sans Fromage</option>
      </select>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" id="cuisson" name="cuisson">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Cuisson</option>
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Seignan</option>
        <option value="3">A poit</option>
        <option value="4">Bien Cuit</option>
      </select>
    </div>   </div> </div>


<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

<div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="e_c" value="1" id="e_c">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Extra Chedar</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="e_b" value="1" id="e_b">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Extra Bacon</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="e_a" value="1" id="e_a">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Extra Autre</label> </div>

    </div>   </div> </div>


<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

<div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_o" value="1" id="s_o">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Oni</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_sal" value="1" id="s_sal">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Sal</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_c" value="1" id="s_c">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Cor</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_sau" value="1" id="s_sau">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Sau</label> </div>

    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">   <div class="input-group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Remove</button>
      </div>   </div> </div>


</div>



<!-- Copy Fields --> <div class="copy hide"> <hr>

    <div class="control-group input-group">

<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" id="formule" name="formule">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Formule</option>
        <option value="1">Classique</option>
        <option value="2">Big</option>
        <option value="3">Veggie</option>
      </select>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary"id="fromage" name="fromage">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Fromage</option>
        <option value="1">Chedar</option>
        <option value="2">Tomme</option>
        <option value="3">Blue</option>
        <option value="4">Chevre</option>
        <option value="5">Cantal</option>
        <option value="6">Reblochon</option>
        <option value="7">Maroille</option>
        <option value="8">Sans Fromage</option>
      </select>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" id="cuisson" name="cuisson">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Cuisson</option>
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Seignan</option>
        <option value="3">A poit</option>
        <option value="4">Bien Cuit</option>
      </select>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

<div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="e_c" value="1" id="e_c">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Extra Chedar</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="e_b" value="1" id="e_b">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Extra Bacon</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="e_a" value="1" id="e_a">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Extra Autre</label> </div>

    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

<div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_o" value="1" id="s_o">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Oni</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_sal" value="1" id="s_sal">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Sal</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_c" value="1" id="s_c">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Cor</label> </div> <div class="form-check">   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="s_sau" value="1" id="s_sau">   <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">S/Sau</label> </div>

    </div>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-1 nopadding">   <div class="form-group">   <div class="input-group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Remove</button>
      </div>   </div> </div>

      </div>

</div>

  </div> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".add-more").click(function(){
          var html = $(".copy").html();
          $(".after-add-more").after(html);
      });

      $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
          $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
      });

    }); </script>

      <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Ajouter</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Confirmer</button>
      </div>

</form> {% endblock %}
```

What would be the best way to allow the users to set as many burgers they want?
I read a little about Flask-WTF but I not sure if that would help in this particular problem and I running out of time for get into a dead end.

Thanks for your answers Stack overflow community.

Answer (score 3):

I could not run the template you shared as it requires `layout.html` and necessary libraries.

Here is an example of creating dynamic text fields using jQuery and getting the values in Flask app.

Let's create a form that can add products dynamically. Later, show the dynamic form values after form submission.

**Directory Structure**

```
├───app.py
├───templates
│   ├───form.html
```

**File contents**

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)    

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return jsonify(request.form)
    return render_template("form.html")
```

`form.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dynamic Form Example</title>
        <script
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Products:
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div id="products"></div>
            <button id="add_item" type="button">Add item</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var count_item = 0;
                $("#add_item").on("click", function(){
                    count_item += 1;
                    $("<input/>").attr({ type: "text", placeholder: "Enter product name",
                        name: "item_"+count_item}).appendTo("#products").wrap($("<div/>"));
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

- Generated dynamic form elements using jQuery:

[image: Generated dynamic form elements using jQuery]

- Display submitted values:

[image: Display submitted values]

**Installed packages**

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

**Running the application**

```
set FLASK_APP=app.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

Replace `set` with `export` if you are not using Windows operating system.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arsho, that's exactly what I want to do, I'll take your code as reference to carry on with my codding, cheers man!

Comment: One question, What should I do if I would like to have a select element instead of input element $("<input/>").attr({ type: "text", placeholder: "Enter product name",
                        name: "item_"+count_item}).appendTo("#products").wrap($("<div/>"));

Comment: Do you want to add options in select element? Or new Select element with predefined options?

Comment: Yes, I want to add options in a select element just like my html document<select class="mdb-select md-form colorful-select dropdown-primary" id="formule" name="formule"> <option value="" disabled selected>Formule</option> <option value="1">Classique</option> <option value="2">Big</option> <option value="3">Veggie</option> </select>, I tried but I have to say that I am a newbie in JS, really thank you for your help

Comment: I found multiple Questions-Answers in Stackoverflow regarding "add option to select using jQuery". Here is an existing answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162574/3129414

I am glad that my example helped you :)

Comment: Yes, your side it's simple and clear just how I want to keep it since I don't know if my project will be accepted or not, thank you I will take a look to the link later cheers

Comment: @AhmedurRahmanShovon what if you have a dynamic `select option` field set `attr` to `multiple`