# Fill DropDownList with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

How can you fill a DropDownList using jQuery?

I have a call to my controller :

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCategories")', { groupId: selectedGroup }, function (categories) {
```

This returns objects from the class Category :

```
  public class Category
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int GroupId { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

How do I get the Id from Category in the DropDownList value and Description from Category in the Text?

This is not working..

```
$.each(categories, function (index, category) {
categoriesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
    value: category.Id,
    text: category.Description
 }));
});
```

This is not working, it gives the message "category not defined".

This is what is in category:

[image]

Comment: Debug. Set a breakpoint and see what's actually in `categories`. Or use `console.log(JSON.stringify(categories, null, 2))` and see what's actually coming back from your service.

Comment: @HereticMonkey updated my question with a debug screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
categoriesSelect.append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", category.Id)
    .text(category.Description));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little mistake, it should be category.id instead of category.Id and category.description instead of category.Description.

Comment: Does this answer your question then? You've written it as an answer, but it doesn't seem to answer why you were getting a message about category not being defined...

Comment: No idea but this seems to work, the message was because I didn't push f11 to continue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your question, that the table of categories that you receive in ajax are objects:

```
 public class Category
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int GroupId { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

your attributes in the answer ajax change `Id -> id`; `GroupId -> groupId`; `Description -> description`. it seems like there is a conversion from your first attribute letter to lowercase. Please take it into account when you build your drop-down list

This code could do the trick. The category array here contains objects in the format of the response that you receive called the call Ajax:

```js
$(function(){
// soit ce tableau de catéogies. Dans ton cas, tu la reçoi après ton appel AJAX
  var categories = [
  {
     id: 1, 
     groupId: "Gp1", 
     description: "Category 1"
  },  
  {
     id: 2, 
     groupId: "Gp1", 
     description: "Category 2"
  },  
  {
     id: 3, 
     groupId: "Gp1", 
     description: "Category 3"
  },  
  {
     id: 4, 
     groupId: "Gp1", 
     description: "Category 4"
  },  
  {
     id: 5, 
     groupId: "Gp1", 
     description: "Category 5"
  }];
  
  // Vide au préalable la liste déroulante sinon, la liste de catégories renvoyées en Ajax viendra s'ajouter à celles déja charger
  $("#myDynamicSelect").html("");
  
  // Avec une boucle, tu parcours ton table de catégories "categories", dans ton cas tu la reçoi dans ta réponse ajax
  $.each(categories, function(i, category){
  // Pour chaque catégorie, tu l'insère dans la liste déroulante. Veille bien à renseigner le bon attribut id de ta liste déroule. ici "#myDynamicSelect"
    var option = new Option( category.description, category.id);
    $("#myDynamicSelect").append(option);
  });   


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myDynamicSelect"></select>
```

Comment: This answer can also help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

Try doing like this,

```
$.get('http://webapi.com' , function (res) {
    if (res) 
    {  
        if (res.customers && res.customers.length > 0) 
        {
            $.each(res.customers, function (id, cus) {
                $("#customers-dropdown").append($('<option></option>').val(cus.id).html(cus.name));
            });
        }
    }
});
```