# Looping through an array and injecting all the values into <select><option>

Tags: javascript, loops

So basically I have this dogs API (https://docs.thedogapi.com/) and im trying to loop somehow and show every single dog's name from the API server into my  tag so people can choose the dog name and show photos and info about it

```
<label for="dogs" name="dogsInput" id="dogsLabel">
    <select id="dogTypes">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>



// JavaScript

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getFetch)

function getFetch(){
    const api_key = '' // not sure if I should post it here so I hide it
    const input = document.querySelector('select').value
    const url = `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds/search`
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data[0])
            document.querySelector('#name').innerHTML = data[0].breeds[0].name
            document.querySelector('img').src = data[0].url
            document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML = "Temperament: " + data[0].breeds[0].temperament
            document.querySelector('h4').innerHTML = "Life span: " + data[0].breeds[0].life_span
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`error ${err}`)
        })
         
}
```

Comment: I did not insert any javascript because I have only the fetch function which is empty, and does not do anything but console.log(data)

Comment: Well, it would help to see the endpoint you're using, and your current code regardless how short, and know whether or not the API needs a key. Otherwise copy a small sample of the JSON into your question so we can help debug it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery)

Comment: @JkAlombro not really, I just try to do it it plain js and not use a library

Answer (score 0):

I'll just assume that the API is returning data, and I'll also assume the data structure of JSON object.

Your fetch should look something like this:

```
...
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

        if (!data) return; // Do something here

        // Get the select element
        var select = document.getElementById("dogTypes");

        // Iterate the data, create a <option> element and append it to
        // the select
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const element = data[i];
            
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = element.Name;
            option.value = element.Value;

            select.appendChild(option);

        }

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`error ${err}`)
    })
```