# How to add options to a Select with JQuery (Ninja Forms)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, ninja-forms

```
jQuery(document).on('nfFormReady', function() {
    
  var textField = jQuery( '#nf-field-3918' );
  var selectField = jQuery( '#nf-field-3962' );

  textField.val( 'New Value' ).trigger( 'change' );

});
```

in this code, I can manipulate a text field like so:
`textField.val( 'New Value' ).trigger( 'change' );`

but How can I add more options to a select element?

I tried this:

```
var inputValue = textField.val();
  var newOption = jQuery( '<option>', {
      value: inputValue,
      text: inputValue
    } );

  selectField.append( newOption );
  selectField.trigger( 'change' );
```

but didnt work

Comment: Please see the following: [Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery)